# How to solve the linear equation $A\circ (XB) + CX = D$

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, hadamard-product, sylvester-equation

How to solve the follow equation $X$ is the variable:
$A\circ (XB) + CX = D$

where $ A \circ B$ is element-wise product or Hadamard product.

if the $A = 1_{n \times n}$. the above equation become
$(XB) + CX = A$ become  Sylvester equation and can be solved.
But how to solve with $A$ is any binary matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the SVD of the leading coefficient
$$\eqalign{A = \sum_k \sigma_k u_k v_k^T = \sum_k w_k v_k^T \cr}$$
and from this decomposition create two sets of diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{W_k &= {\rm Diag}(w_k) \cr V_k &= {\rm Diag}(v_k) \cr}$$
The elementwise/Hadamard product can now be replaced by a sum
$$\eqalign{D = CX + \sum_k W_k XB V_k \cr}$$
Solve this equation via vectorization 
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(D)&=\Big(I\otimes C + \sum_k V_kB^T\otimes W_k\Big)\,{\rm vec}(X)\cr
{\rm vec}(X)&=\Big(I\otimes C+\sum_k V_kB^T\otimes W_k\Big)^+\,{\rm vec}(D)\cr
X&={\rm Mat}\bigg(\Big(I\otimes C+\sum_k V_kB^T\otimes W_k\Big)^+\,{\rm vec}(D)\bigg)\cr
}$$
where $M^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $M$, and Mat() is the inverse of the vec() operation.

Comment: nice job. any recommend material for how to vectorization an equation? thanks